# Alluxio on kubernetes(EKS) supports workers only with DaemonSet kind? Or we can deploy workers using Deployment kind and specify number of workers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, alluxio

We are running Alluxio on our apps EKS cluster. And the cluster deployment creating worker pods on each eks node as worker deployment kind is DaemonSet. Thus worker pods are consuming resources in all EKS nodes. We want to limit the worker pods to some specific count. Is it possible to use deployment kind for alluxio workers?

Comment: Possible? Yes, since a Daemonset is a Deployment... But can't you use anti affinity rules on a daemonset to only target specific nodes?

Answer (score 0):

We can deploy worker pods with kind set to Deployment, so that pods will not be created on each eks nodes, And also we can mention the replicas to workers for maintaining high availability.